# Is it OK to use system("CLS") with Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I was looking around on the Microsoft forums about clearing the console in the Windows Console Application. I was looking for an alternative to `system("CLS")` because I heard that it was bad to use and unportable.

All I found was to use `system("CLS")` and there weren't any alternatives that seemed to work.

In Visual Studio 2017 (the version I'm using) is it OK<sup>1</sup> to use `system("CLS")` and `system("pause")`?

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>***Ok*** as in it is not bad to use.</sub>

Comment: Alternative and you don't need to depend on system command  `cout << string(50, '\n');`

Comment: It would have some of the same disadvantages as [`system("pause");`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong).

Comment: OT: The only use-case, where I see screen clearing to be useful, is ASCII-based console games. Apart from those: I fail to understand the need for it.

Comment: That does work, but I would prefer the text to be at the top. I am making an ASCII-based console game.

Comment: you can use `clrscr();` , present in `conio.h`

Comment: Visual Studio removed `clrscr();` from `conio.h`

Comment: Try this link : http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o/  It contains different way to achieve clear screen

Comment: Thanks, seemed to work on there but is it alright to user `system("CLS");` once?